# jQuery marquee not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, marquee

I am using jQuery marquee plugin.

Here is an example : http://bit.ly/1jmpXrY

When text scroll ended and when start again i want to pause the scroll at left `0` (main wrapper) and start again from left `0` like [jquery.simplemarquee](http://bit.ly/1VODolp) .

```js
$(function () {
    
    $('.marquee')
        .bind('beforeStarting', function(){
        
        $('.js-marquee .ogg:first').css('margin-left', '-' + ($('.marquee').width() -5) + 'px');
           
         })
       .marquee({
        duration: 5000, duplicated: true
    })
    
    
    
    setInterval(function(){
    $('.marquee').marquee('toggle');
},    $('.marquee .ogg').width());
    
    
    
});
```

```css
.marquee {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #ccc;
}

.wrapper{
    width:150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.marquee/1.3.1/jquery.marquee.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="marquee">
        <div class="ogg" >jQuery marquee is the best marquee plugin in the world </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is way juddery for me. Why not use jquery.simplemarquee if it does what you want.

Comment: Because jquery.simplemarquee not working with jQuery 1.7.2 on opera @AlexK.